# Top/bottom margin with Masonry stacking

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-masonry

I'm using JQuery and Masonry and as you can see from the image the boxes doesn't stack properly. The side margins are great but the top/bottom gives random amount of large space in between.

Anybody who can help me here?

CSS for the boxes:

```
div.article {
background-color: white;
margin-right: 6px;
padding: 20px 10px;
width: 155px;}
```

Screenshot of problem:
https://skitch.com/subzane/f8n36/2010-andreas-normans-blogg

**Solution:**
It seems the error only appeared when using custom fonts. And to fix that, the script must be loaded using Using $(window).load() instead of $(document).ready().

Answer (score 2):

Assuming div.article is also your masonry item selector, you need to have it floated left.

Comment: float: left doesn't change anything. Tried it.

Comment: It seems that the problem only exists when I'm using custom font-faces. Switching to a normal web font solves it. However, I really would like to use masonry with a custom font :)

ideas?

Comment: Soution: Using $(window).load() instead of $(document).ready() solves it :)

Comment: @Andreas: Ah cool, might I suggest the jQuery ready handler for your future needs:  http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: but $(document).ready() was the thing that bugged it. I have to use $(window).load()

Comment: @Andreas ah my mistake, I always get confused by that syntax and forget its the same thing as $()

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an ancient question, but I had this exact problem. The solution, in my case, was adding the width/height to the images that were within some if my item containers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, window.load() works but as I've dug more I found that there was an input type hidden in between some of the items. Take a look if you have any tag in between of your item list.